# Figuring out file extension before downloading

Tags: r, web-scraping, download

I'm doing a project that requires going into a database of the brazillian equivalent of the FTC and downloading a few files (which I will later process), and I want to automate this using R.

My problem is that when naming the file, I have to tell it the file extension, and I don't know what it will be (usually it will be a scanned pdf, but sometimes it will be an html file). Here an example:

https://sei.cade.gov.br/sei/modulos/pesquisa/md_pesq_processo_exibir.php?0c62g277GvPsZDAxAO1tMiVcL9FcFMR5UuJ6rLqPEJuTUu08mg6wxLt0JzWxCor9mNcMYP8UAjTVP9dxRfPBcbZvmE_iaYkTbpPedZsRpa1llf9W8WXxdUJxor5q0IiE

I want the first and the tenth file. Downloading them is easy:

```
download.file("https://sei.cade.gov.br/sei/modulos/pesquisa/md_pesq_documento_consulta_externa.php?DZ2uWeaYicbuRZEFhBt-n3BfPLlu9u7akQAh8mpB9yPDzrBMElK1BGz7u3NcOFP7-Z5s9oDvQR1K4ELVR_nmNlPto_G3CRD_y2Hu6JLvHZVV2LDxnr4dccffqX3xlEao", destfile = 'C:/teste/teste1', mode = 'wb')
download.file("https://sei.cade.gov.br/sei/modulos/pesquisa/md_pesq_documento_consulta_externa.php?DZ2uWeaYicbuRZEFhBt-n3BfPLlu9u7akQAh8mpB9yPaFy5S3krC8lTKjlRbfodOIg2NArJmAFS5PyUEHL3hnJYr8VG9zLGdNts6K99Ht673e_ZPr2gr3Cw7r8zJqRiH", destfile = 'C:/teste/teste2', mode = 'wb')
```

The thing is, I don't know which one is a pdf file and which one is an html file without manually trying to open them with another program. Is there any way to tell R to automatically add the correct file extension when downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `httr` package, you can get the content-type header which will help you decide what type of file it is. You can use the `HEAD()` function to get the headers of the files. For example with your URLs

```
urls <- c(
  "https://sei.cade.gov.br/sei/modulos/pesquisa/md_pesq_documento_consulta_externa.php?DZ2uWeaYicbuRZEFhBt-n3BfPLlu9u7akQAh8mpB9yPDzrBMElK1BGz7u3NcOFP7-Z5s9oDvQR1K4ELVR_nmNlPto_G3CRD_y2Hu6JLvHZVV2LDxnr4dccffqX3xlEao", 
  "https://sei.cade.gov.br/sei/modulos/pesquisa/md_pesq_documento_consulta_externa.php?DZ2uWeaYicbuRZEFhBt-n3BfPLlu9u7akQAh8mpB9yPaFy5S3krC8lTKjlRbfodOIg2NArJmAFS5PyUEHL3hnJYr8VG9zLGdNts6K99Ht673e_ZPr2gr3Cw7r8zJqRiH"
)
```

You can write a helper function

```
get_content_type <- function(x) {
    unname(sapply(x, function(x) headers(HEAD(x))[["content-type"]]))
}

get_content_type(urls)
# [1] "application/pdf;"              "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

These return mime-type, but you can grep for things like "pdf" to save as  a PDF or "html" for web pages. Not sure what other types of files might be available. There is no "correct" file name for a given file type so you'd need to make that decision yourself.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The only other thing it can be is (very rarely) a zip file, so I probably only need to check if it's one the three.